# Running Xcode console

Tags: iphone

I want to run my iphone app with Instruments to check on memory usage, but I also want to be able to see my Console output as I go along. Is there currently no way to do this? You can only seemingly start either Instruments or Console in XCode itself.

Comment: Good question. I don't think you can!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run your application from within Xcode to have the console output piped there.  While your application is running, start Instruments and choose an appropriate instrument.  Under Default Target in the menu bar, select iPhone or Computer (whichever is appropriate for what you're testing), and under Attach to Process find the name of your executable.

When you click the record button, your application should start being profiled under Instruments while having its console output directed to Xcode.  Unfortunately, this attachment process will need to come after the application has started, so you may have to profile the startup of your application separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the console in the organizer panel while running instruments, its not ideal but its a solution!

To find it open the organizer, click on your device and then click on the Console tab

Answer (score 0):

I hear that there are a number of improvements to the developer tools in Snow Leopard; perhaps this will be one of them?